# throw exception if i use multithreading in optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

```
2018-08-22 18:56:18,007 61345 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase [Line:142] -     CH step (910), time spent (45305), score (-456init/0hard/0soft), selected move count (810), picked move ([Lecture #ClassUnit # 1 - Curriculum 641#语文 @ null null {null -> Period-0}, Lecture #ClassUnit # 1 - Curriculum 641#语文 @ null null {null -> Room 801}]).
2018-08-22 18:56:18,016 61354 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase [Line:142] -     CH step (911), time spent (45314), score (-456init/0hard/0soft), selected move count (40), picked move (Lecture #ClassUnit # 1 - Curriculum 641#语文 @ Period-0 Room 801 {null -> null}).
2018-08-22 18:56:18,045 61383 [main] INFO  o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase [Line:160] - Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (45343), best score (-456init/0hard/0soft), score calculation speed (8509/sec), step total (912).

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Local Search phase (1) needs to start from an initialized solution, but the planning variable (Lecture.teacher) is uninitialized for the entity (Lecture #ClassUnit # 1 - Curriculum 641#语文 @ Period-0 Room 801).
Maybe there is no Construction Heuristic configured before this phase to initialize the solution.
Or maybe the getter/setters of your planning variables in your domain classes aren't implemented correctly.

    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.AbstractPhase.assertWorkingSolutionInitialized(AbstractPhase.java:220)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.phaseStarted(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:118)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:64)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:87)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:191)
    at org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.Solver$solve.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
    at com.bugu.queen.service.solver.CourseScheduleSolverFactoryServiceTest.createSolver(CourseScheduleSolverFactoryServiceTest.groovy:223)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
```

however, if i disable multiple cpu by changing config xml, like

```
<!-- To solve faster by saturating multiple CPU cores -->
    <moveThreadCount>AUTO</moveThreadCount>
```

so, is it a bug or my mistake?

and i check the teacher range before getRangeList return, i am sure it is not empty..

and i use

```
<constructionHeuristic>
        <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>

    </constructionHeuristic>
```

Comment: Without multithreaded solving, do you also see the long line `Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: ..., best score (-456init/0hard/0soft)`? That says there are 456 uninitialized entities, so it's normal that Local Search doesn't want to start. It's not normal that the multithreaded CH doesn't initialize them.

Comment: What happens if you turn on enviromnentMode FULL_ASSERT and give it more time?

Comment: that's the exception on condition enviromnentMode  FULL_ASSERT and 1 hour terminate

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet no exception, works fine

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the `Move.rebase()` goes wrong. That's probably caused by something related to where you put your `@PlanningId` annotation.

I'd like to know exactly what went wrong, so OptaPlanner's FULL_ASSERT mode can detect it sooner (and probably explain it better). Please create a jira with a reproducer.

Comment: i am sorry, there is any url or guide about "create jira with a reproducer"